# Regex giving StackOverflowError on long input string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find HTML tags in my code using the regex `<(.|\n)+?>`.

Now I have encountered a string where this regex is giving me a `StackOverflowError`.

For the first time it finds bold part in the string through the group function but next time give the below mentioned exception.

I am using the following string:

```
"In SCCM 2012 there is a completely revised version of the Mobile Device
Management part. Sure, this was already there in SCCM 2007, but hey, would YOU
want to "manage" ancient Windows CE or Windows Mobile 5.0 devices? I didn't
think so too. Also, in the SCCM 2007 era, Bring Your Own Device (BYOD) wasn't
as hot as it is today, with everyone wanting to bring in and use their own
Tablets, Smarphones and laptops. Now with SCCM 2012, there is proper support
for BYOD. Yeah! For a nice overview of this, see this video of Principal
Program manager Jeffrey Sutherland, talking about Mobile Device Management in
SCCM 2012. Light and Depth Management We can define two types of device
management in SCCM 2012: -> Light Management **<- Working through Exchange
ActiveSync, we leverage on the existing Exchange Device Policies, to do light
management of the device (remote wipe, lockdown etc) Why do we want this? It's
already in Exchange right? Well, the Exchange admins might not be very
concerned with specific end-users devices as they are with handling the
mailflow, so this task may better fit with the desktop/enduser/device
management team in your organization. They are the ones working with SCCM 2012,
and they are the ones most interested in gathering information about, and
managing the devices. Also, SCCM provides some very nice Reporting on these
devices.** ->In-Depth Management <- The other type is the In-Depth Management
of Mobile Devices This does not work through EAS, but through two new SCCM
Roles that have been introduced in SCCM 2012; the Enrollment Point and the
Enrollment Proxy point. In-depth management can be done in two ways; - Enroll
the mobile devices into SCCM by installing the Mobile Device Client on them.
Only on supported mobile OS's.(Currently WinMobile 6.1, 6.5 and Nokia Symbian
Belle) .Offers most features. - Enroll the mobile devices into SCCM by
installing the Legacy Mobile Device Client on it. Only on supported mobile
OS's, which currently are ancient WinCE 5, 6 and 7, and WinMo 6.0. Less
features, but still way more options than with EAS. For a good comparison of
all features on all three scenarios( EAS, Mobile Device Client on device, and
Legacy Mobile device client), see this page on Technet. Note that both in-depth
solutions require a PKI Infrastructure, because of the Certificates that are
used on the devices! So, more on the In-Depth part later, let's first get the
EAS connected. (Yes, you can also choose hybrid solutions, ie. managing with
both EAS and through the Enrollment) Configuration of Mobile Device Management
through Exchange So, how do we set this up? First the prereqs: an Exchange 2010
SP1 server (or Exchange Online(office365),and a working SCCM 2012 server (duh)
and a network connection between them. Then we have to establish a connection
between the SCCM server and the Exchange (CAS) server. We click Add exchange
server and get the wizard: Specifiy the name of the exchange CAS server... Hey,
look at this screen. A precise listing of the exchange permissions that the
connector account requires. I'd say this calls for a new RBAC  Role in
Exchange! So, lets first create a serviceaccount for this connection and assign
the proper exchange permissions to it. Now i am going to be assigning Read-Only
rights to this service account, 'cause i just want to get data from EAS about
the devices, and not do any remote wiping. Which is by the way also how
Microsoft IT did this (read here ) Then continue through the wizard: I just set
this to Weekly Full discovery, and Delta discovery twice a day. So, after this
wizard, the connection has been established with the CAS server. As you can
see, the path /powershell has been added to the targetpath of the Exchange
server. Which makes sense, because all it really does is fire up PowerShell
cmdlets against the CAS, to get information from it. So, do we see any devices
now? First lets kick off a discovery cycle: And behold: Well that device has my
name written all over it (tee-hee) So, what can we do with it then? Well, not
an awfull lot: Wipe, Block, and.. hmm. well. Lets have a look at those Reports
then: Wow. That's a lot of Reports Built-in. Very cool! So far for this then.
Time to get really busy, and fire up an old Windows Mobile 6.5 phone, and start
doing some real managing. In the Next post that is."
```

The exception got is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$LazyLoop.match(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Check the exception stack trace or post more lines of the stacktrace here. A method call cycle should be shown.

Comment: Its a very long stacktrace. Moreover all of it is related to the regex functions used internally

Comment: Have you tried this expression? `<[^>]++>`

Comment: Not sure why you have a problem; Regexr handles it just fine! http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?311l9

Comment: regex is giving this problem both in my own code and a small standalone code

Comment: @Tomalak Ur regex only finds the data inside the tags only once, then it exits.

Comment: But there _is_ only one match for your regex.

Comment: text starting with "<-Working" is one , the other starts with "<- The other type"

Comment: Right Ray ..Only one match is present...

Comment: @ tomalak can u give me the diff between the regex i was giving and the one u gave to me

Answer (score 0):

You can use -Xss jvm flag (the stack size for each thread) if really there is no loop

Comment: The problem is when it goes to find the pattern again , it goes into some loop which ultimately results in stackover flow